# What are the difficulties/issues to consider when allowing ZIP file uploads?

Tags: php, pdf, zip, uploading

I allow PDF files to be uploaded to my site (PHP).

I would like to offer the ability to also allow .zip files which contain PDF files in directories so it is easier for users to simply zip a directory and upload one file instead of uploading multiple zip files individual.

For those of you who offer a .zip file upload feature to your (PHP) website, what are the technical, security, and other issues you have faced?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the .zip gets unpacked eventually you would have to make sure the directory they get unpacked in is unreachable by the the clients' browsers (with .htaccess or by placing it outside the web root directory), and even in that case I'd still monitor the contents of the unpacked .zip to make sure they didn't contain anything that might prove harmful (php or other files run by the server, html spoofs).

Another issue is i guess the `upload_max_filesize` set in php.ini, you can make sure it can be set big enough to suit your purposes before you start coding.

edit: also read [sarnold's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5548370/what-are-the-difficulties-issues-to-consider-when-allowing-zip-file-uploads/5548503#5548503) ;)

Comment: not to forget the zip bombs. They are extremely tricky. They are verry verry small but if you try to extract them you blow your server because the take some TB to extract. So actually you need some kind of antivirus check if you ever extract them. if you only save them nothing should happen.

Answer (score 1):

[Be careful how you unpack the zip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_bomb), you could find yourself consuming far more resources than you expected. Perhaps some `setrlimit(2)` resource limits before unpacking would be wise.

The `unzip(1)` utility has several nice safety features built in; the `-^` command line option **turns off** control-character filtering, so make sure you don't touch this :) and the `-:` command line option **allows** stupid pathnames like `../../../../etc/passwd`. Make sure you're on at least version 5.50, so that those stupid pathnames are forbidden by default. (And don't use that command line option. I mention the options just so you can more easily find the documentation for them. :)

If you use an API, make sure it has options to prevent both kinds of silly filenames.

Comment: Making sure that your web-server user is unprivileged and sandboxed would go a long way towards avoiding this kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, php can handle zip files pretty efficiently. Difficulties/Issues that I can think of is, while accessing the file where We need to extract the zip first, and then retrieve the actual needed file. Due to that reason, extracting a zip, might consume additional amount of server time, depending on the size of the file itself.

Where As, during uploads, I do not suppose there is any difficulties or issues specially emphasized on `zip` types.

Comment: To add my two cents, if you can use ClamAV, there are some [3rd party libs](http://www.clamav.net/lang/en/download/third-party-tools/3rdparty-library/) (for PHP too) if you want virus-check uploaded files.